# Drop down displaying values depending on value in other drop down c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down lists, the first one displays different species of animals and I want the second one to display breeds depending on which species was chosen.

In my database, all breeds of a species have a matching id.

Code for first dropdown:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDown_Species();
}

public void DropDown_Species()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        MySqlCommand sql_country = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Species FROM breed", cs);
        //connection string opend
        cs.Open();

        MySqlDataReader ddlvalue;
        ddlvalue = sql_country.ExecuteReader();

        petSpecies.DataSource = ddlvalue;
        petSpecies.DataValueField = "Species";
        petSpecies.DataTextField = "Species";
        petSpecies.DataBind();
        petSpecies.Items.Insert(0, "Select Species");
        // connection string closed
        cs.Close();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Code for second dropdown:

```
protected void petsBreed_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (petSpecies.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format(
             "SELECT * FROM (Breed.breed)", petSpecies.Text), cs);
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader petsSpecies = cd.ExecuteReader();
        petsBreed.DataSource = petsSpecies;
        petsBreed.DataValueField = "Breed";
        petsBreed.DataTextField = "Breed";
        petsBreed.DataBind();
        petsBreed.Items.Insert(0, "Select Breed");
        cs.Close();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the second drop down.

Very new to C#.

Can anybody show me where the problem is and/or how to make this idea work?

Comment: Second dropdown - I think the problem is in your database call. Can you put a breakpoint after the call and see what data is coming through ?

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that nothing is coming through in the first place. I think I need to just write a completely new database call but I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: You have to use for loop and get each item in list.

Comment: DO something like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay but I'm not entirely sure how to do this, would it be possible for you to create an example?

Comment: Ahhh!...Check the answer below. Let me know if you'r still stuck. @win has it correct

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `string.Format` but not using the argument in there ...?

```
MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format(
         "SELECT * FROM (Breed.breed)", petSpecies.Text), cs);
```

Shouldn't you use string format like:

```
 var use_it_properly = string.Format ("Hi {0}, now you're using it properly", name);
```

otherwise, you're not relaying on the input which in your case should be the selected specie?

---

read more on MSDN then : [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Example from that site:

```
DateTime dat = new DateTime(2012, 1, 17, 9, 30, 0); 
string city = "Chicago";
int temp = -16;
string output = String.Format("At {0} in {1}, the temperature was {2} degrees.",
                              dat, city, temp);
Console.WriteLine(output);
// The example displays the following output: 
//    At 1/17/2012 9:30:00 AM in Chicago, the temperature was -16 degrees.
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so I'm not entirely sure but I will try and implement this. Thank you

Comment: Since you want the input of the 2nd to depend on the 1st, you need to select from the DB something based on that selected value. You can use the string format, but you'll have to put in the part you need in there .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MySQL. Here is what you can do with SqlDataSource.

### DataBase (Table name is Breed)

```
BreedId    Species    Breed
1          dog        Alsatian
2          dog        pitbull
3          dog        Shetland sheepdog
4          dog        Boxer
5          cat        Dragon Li
6          cat        Australian Mist
7          cat        Korat
```

### ScreenShot

[image] [image]

### ASPX

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSpecies" runat="server" DataSourceID="Species"
    DataTextField="Species" DataValueField="Species" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Species" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Species] FROM [Breed]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListBreed" runat="server"
   DataSourceID="breed" DataTextField="Breed" DataValueField="Breed">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="breed" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Breed] FROM [Breed] WHERE Species=@Species">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListSpecies" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Species" Type="String" 
           DefaultValue="cat" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Make sure that `AutoPostBack="True"` for `DropDownListSpecies`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm having a bit of difficulty reading this, would it be possible for you to display the C# code?

Comment: There is not C# code because both DropDownLists use SqlDataSource.